# Concatenate values from one column per group

Tags: r, tidyr

I want to concatenate values per group that are now in one column. The following is a short version of the data frame I want to wrangle.

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- tibble::tribble(
  ~county,  ~party,
      "A",   "VVD",
      "A",    "GL",
      "A", "Local",
      "B",   "D66",
      "B", "Local"
  )
```

Now I want to create one row per county with all the parties in their own column:

```
df2 <- tibble::tribble(
  ~county, ~party1, ~party2, ~party3,
      "A",   "VVD",    "GL", "Local",
      "B",   "D66", "Local",      NA
  )
```

To later concatenate with `unite()` and replace the underscores for comma's and Remove the NA's.

```
df2 %>%
  unite(party, c("party1", "party2", "party3")) %>%
  mutate(party = gsub("_NA", "", party),
         party = gsub("_", ", ", party))
```

My desired `df` output:

```
  county party         
  <chr>  <chr>         
1 A      VVD, GL, Local
2 B      D66, Local
```

Answer (score 1):

We can do this by creating a sequence column and `spread`

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>%
   group_by(county) %>% 
   mutate(v1 = paste0('party', row_number())) %>% 
   spread(v1, party)
# A tibble: 2 x 4
# Groups:   county [2]
#  county party1 party2 party3
#  <chr>  <chr>  <chr>  <chr> 
#1 A      VVD    GL     Local 
#2 B      D66    Local  <NA>
```

---

For the second output, we group by 'county' and `paste` the elements of 'party

```
df %>%
  group_by(county) %>%
  summarise(party = toString(party))
# A tibble: 2 x 2
#  county party         
#  <chr>  <chr>         
#1 A      VVD, GL, Local
#2 B      D66, Local
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df %>%
    group_by(county) %>%
    dplyr::summarise( paste0(party, collapse = ", "))
```

You should prompt `?group_by` (`?paste0` .. etc) to R console if anything is unclear.

Comment: Code only answers are meh, try to add supporting language to make it more helpful for the asker and future visitors who might not be `dplyr` wizards

Comment: Just added @Nate :-)